# Is farming Zoltun Kulle more lucrative than the Butcher in Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been getting pretty bored of Act I Inferno as my group is slowly working on Act III. When we farm, we usually just do Butcher runs, but I was curious to see if running Zoltun Kulle would result in better drops and more gold. He's a pretty easy fight with a few caveats, but I've only killed him a few times.

Is Zoltun Kulle a better farming target than  the Butcher in Inferno mode?

Comment: Doesn't this depend largely on your individual character build?  Your character might find one boss easier while others find the opposite.

Comment: @GnomeSlice, I run with a group, and 1 tank + dps is a fairly common group comp. I tried to communicate that this was for group runs.

Comment: You should expressly mention that in the question then, because otherwise it's pretty localized to your character.

Comment: Thought "we" and "group" was pretty descriptive as more than 1...

Comment: And it was pretty express, I didn't spend a lot of time posting it :P

Comment: Your 'Group' could be any number of players, for all we know.  Just trying to help out.

Comment: Removing factors like difficulty and how well your group handles the encounter, you have the potential to get better loot from Zulle than Butcher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, mainly because Zoltun Kulle is an act 2 boss. Act 2 drops can yield tier 17 items, where act 1 can only yield tier 16 items. To get the best drops possible you have to farm act 3.

While the drops probabilities should be somewhat equal between the two, the second one can drop better items

Answer (score 5):

Didn't want to answer my own question but it was to long for a comment and it seems other people are interested as well...

So I, a tank monk, have been running Zoltun Kulle with my mage buddy today and the results are very good so far.  We've only done 7 runs so far but the drops we are getting are vastly superior to the act 1 Butcher drops.

I knew they would be better, but we weren't sure if you wouldn't start seeing quality gear until acts 3 and 4.  So far we've found 1 set item, which was exciting for us since we never found any in act 1 and all the legendarys we found in act 1 were level 55 and 56.  We are also finding much higher quality yellows that we've been selling from 100k-750k so far, much better compared to the 20k-100k from butcher sales.

As far as just gold being found and vendor sales, I earn a little, but very slowly, and my buddy the mage loses money due to repairs and potions.  The vast upgrade in drop quality has more than made up for this though.

I'd still like to hear other peoples opinions and results.

Answer (score 1):

I have found farming Kulle to be atleast as effective as farming Butcher, and a lot more fun due to the challenge and exitement for good loot. 
I'm a wizard with 36k dmg, 24k health and 300 resistances, and the gold drops more than make up for my repair costs while playing with a tank and another ranged.

Answer (score -2):

Been soloing T6 Zulle for a bit now and I'm starting to feel I've gotten everything I can from him. Is there a list of items he's able to drop or is it fair game for everything? I got a lot of really great drops earlier on when I wasn't able to play T6, but he hasn't dropped anything above a rare for quite a long while on any difficulty.
Zulle is definitely best to farm though because there's minimal walking involved to get to him. Most other bosses require you to trudge through a level or two in order to get to them;not old Zoltun Kulle though. :p